# Split query with includes into multiple queries

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using EF5 Code First and have a query such as this:

```
        var query = DbSet.Include(ent => ent.Websites)
            .Include(ent => ent.Addresses)
            .Include(ent => ent.IndustryType)
            .Include(ent => ent.Factors)
            .Include(ent => ent.Factors.Select(fact => fact.Objectives))
            .Include(ent => ent.DmpNodes)
            .Include(ent => ent.DmpNodes.Select(node => node.DmpNodeConnections));
```

If I use more than 4 includes, the query executes very slow. I already know why that is.

I could omit e.g. the DmpNodes include and load that navigation property with lazy loading, but that will result in hundreds of queries.

I'm looking for a way to split up this query so I can first load the entities with e.g. Addresses, IndustryType and Factors. And with a second query fill those entities with the rest.

Is this possible or is there another good solution?

Comment: IF you do separate requests that use the same context, EF will automatically join related entities in memory.

Comment: Can you please show me what this looks like in code? At the end I need entity objects with all navigation properties filled.

Comment: Well, just write a test on your side. Select Websites and then Addresses in a separate query using the same context and see if navigation properties are filled correctly!

Comment: Is there any use case where you need _all_ includes? I would strongly prefer to have queries that serve specific use cases.

Comment: @MaxS I didn't realize it was THAT simple :-) Works like a charm.

Comment: I've post my comments as an aswer so that other guys facing the same issue will know how to deal with it!

Comment: I don't understand how 2 separate queries then doing relationship fixup is better than getting the data in 1 query. Unless you want a subset of the DmpNodes. Then that would be a conditional include wouldn't it? ...http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do separate L2E queries that use the same context, EF will automatically join related entities in memory.

Just write a test on your side. Select `Websites` and then `Addresses` in a separate query using the same context and navigation properties will be filled correctly!

Comment: Sharing a context among requests is a bad idea. Using this for getting related entities is an even worse idea, because it makes the code dependent of execution history. You can however use the feature of relationship fixup within _one_ request (and context) by explixitly loading collections.

Comment: I totally agree with the fact that `Context` lifetime should be as short as possible. By _requests_ I don't mean `HTTPRequest` but DB requests (L2E query). I've edited my answer.